# Pandas: get average dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have 50 dataframes with one structures, but values are different. How can I get average dataframe from all this?

```
       active nodes
graph              
0               128
1               128
2               128
3               127
4               126
5               126
6               126
7               126
8               126
9               125
10              124
```

Answer (score 5):

Add all your DataFrames to a list, concatenate them and calculate the mean of each row:

```
dfs = [df1, df2, ... dfn]
pd.concat(dfs, axis=1).mean(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `numpy` instead.

Assume the list of dataframes `dfs`

```
dfs = [pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(10, 10))) for _ in range(50)]
```

Then calculate the mean by using `np.concatenate` then taking the `mean`.  But being `numpy` this should also be quicker.

```
pd.Series(np.concatenate([df.values for df in dfs], axis=1).mean(1), dfs[0].index)

0    4.472
1    4.722
2    4.644
3    4.574
4    4.624
5    4.446
6    4.548
7    4.606
8    4.440
9    4.442
dtype: float64
```

---

***timing***

[image]

Comment: A bit compact version : `np.mean([df.values for df in dfs],(0,2))`.